# Jackson - parse & map complex nested JSON to not-so-POJO with Parent/Child classes

Tags: java, json, jackson2

Ive got the basic pieces working for creating POJO objects Ive already defined  that I can map basic JSON structures to those objects, But I have the need to parse a certain API that returns different types of objects, and you never know what type it will return

Now, of all the data that the API could return, I have been able to create generic Parent classes and then the appropriate child classes that presumably would allow correct representation of anything the API could hand out, but how to tell the mappings to do the work in this scenario?

Im using something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    TestParent myHeader = mapper.readValue(headerJson, TestParent.class);
    System.out.println(myHeader.getWhatAmI());
```

Where TestParent is a super of TestHeader and I hoped the mapper could go figure out based on all the JSON present that the JSON returned should fit best into a TestHeader, and then map to that, but it does just use TestParent and stop there. I will note in this case I dont really know at the time I call the API which type of object really does get returned., which is why I believe I have to specify TestParent here.  But when I run this, the String "Parent" gets returned.

---

```
{ "level": 1,
  "proto": "test",
  "id": 123 }
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"level",
"proto",
})

    public class TestParent implements Serializable
    {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6150510755722173178L;

        @JsonProperty("level")
        protected Integer level;

        @JsonProperty("proto")
        protected String proto;

        protected String whatAmI;

        public TestParent() {
            whatAmI = "Parent";
        }


        @JsonProperty("level")
        public Integer getLevel() {
            return level;
        }

        @JsonProperty("proto")
            public String getProto() {
            return proto;
        }

        public String getWhatAmI() {
            return whatAmI;
        }
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"priority"
})

public class Child1 extends TestParent implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8750271072576382586L;

@JsonProperty("priority")
private String pri;

public Child1() {
    super();
    whatAmI = "Child1";
}

@JsonProperty("priority")
public String getPriority() {
    return pri;
}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"priority"
})

public class Child2 extends TestParent implements Serializable
{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8750271072576382586L;

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;

public Child2() {
    super();
    whatAmI = "Child2";
}

@JsonProperty("id")
public Integer getPriority() {
    return id;
}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import TestParent;
import Child1;
import Child2;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{ \"level\": 1,\"proto\": \"test\",\"id\": 123}";
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        TestParent someObject = mapper.readValue(json, TestParent.class);
        System.out.println(someObject.getWhatAmI());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a few examples of input json and how it represents types of objects?

Comment: Add the JSON and TestParent class in the question, with limited information its not easy to follow what you are doing.

Comment: thanks - Ive loaded up there very simple example.

Comment: and how is jackson supposed to figure out the concrete class from the provided json ? I myself couldn't figure it out.  perhaps yuo need to add "whoami" property